# How can I make this function acccording to timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to return time according to my choice of timezone. How can I do that?

```
let currentTime = () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var hh = String(today.getHours())
    var mm = String(today.getMinutes()) //January is 0!
    var ss = String(today.getSeconds())

    console.log(hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss)
    return hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Date.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) function for this purpose.

We can pass in the time zone using one of the IANA zones (here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), this will give us the time in hh:mm:ss format in that zone.

For example:

```js
let currentTime = (timeZone) => {
    const today = new Date();
    return today.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", { timeZone });
}

const timeZones = ["Asia/Singapore", "Asia/Kolkata", "Europe/Berlin",  "Europe/London", "America/Los_Angeles"];

console.log("Timezone".padEnd(20) + " ", "Current Time");
timeZones.forEach(timeZone => console.log(timeZone.padEnd(20) + " ", currentTime(timeZone)));
```